# data conversion in python

Tags: python, data-conversion

I have crawled data online. these data are saved in a mongodb. the day is always before month and year. I just need the month and year.I want to remove the number in front of the month, the data frame are not the same,like:

20-21 May 2008,
19 March 2008,
16-17 September 2010,
5 September 2011,

these data are saved as strings in python, is there any function to remove the numbers of day in python? these are about 3000 data,so I think I need a cycle to deal the problem.
[image]

Comment: It's unclear what your expected output is. What have you tried already?

Comment: what's your concrete input, dataframe? if so, post its definition

Comment: As far as I understand you just want to parse dates such that the "day" part is deleted? Is the day always before month and year?

Comment: please update the question with input example and desired output

Comment: yes, I have crawled data online. these data are saved in a mongodb. the day is always before month and year. I just need the month and year.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because the info you want to remove is all numeric, white space, and possibly a hyphen, you can easily do this for each date with this:

```
month_year = days_month_year.lstrip('0123456789- \t')
```

This should be reasonably reliable, since you want to keep the string starting with the month, which is always going to be alphabetic.

There are, of course, many different ways to do this.  You could also do regular expressions to extract out what you want, but the above is the simplest.

```
>>> s = '20-21 May 2008'
>>> s.lstrip('0123456789- \t')
'May 2008'
```

Comment: is the year  removed too?

Comment: @Goodmanyeahhh  Nope. Only the day/days and the white space before the Month. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
pd.Series(['20-21 May 2008', '19 March 2008', '16-17 September 2010', '5 September 2011']).str.extract('(\w{3,}\s\d{4})', expand=False)
```

This will extract the required string and would create a new Series object.